# how to apply javasript date and time format in double digit in the available codes below

Tags: javascript, html

just wondering how the time format can be used with the codes below??
currently showing time and date both in single-digit like

```
Time= 18:5:5 instead 18:05:05
date= 5-6-2021 instead 05-06-2021
```

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getDate()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getFullYear();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = dateTime;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addZero(number) {
  return number.toString().length === 0 ? `0${number}` : number;
}

const today = new Date();
const day = addZero(today.getDate());
const month = addZero(today.getMonth()+1);
const year = today.getFullYear();

document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = `${day}-${month}-${year}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.prototype.padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```js
const str1 = '5';

console.log(str1.padStart(2, '0'));
// expected output: "05"
```